# A phone call from Derek

Tags: knowledge, story, geography, seasonal

**Today I got a phone call from my Australian mate Derek and it went something like this:**

D: Help!! Things have gone real fzfzfz during the holiday trip to Thailand!!

Me: Oh!!! How can I help and what’s that burning sound in the back it is making it hard to hear you??

D: Pay close attention I got limited fzfzfz life and fzfzfz

Me: You are now cutting out.

D: Ok I fzfzfz where I am but I see something on the ground.

Me: Ok…

D: The fzfzfz Like a Forest where a bird is running away from a snail.

Me: Sorry how is that helpful?

D: And the sky is clear but dark and upside down with a co fzfzfz

Me: What on Earth are you on about?? isn’t it daytime in Thailand at the moment.

D: You are correct it is daytime but… beeeeeep

*…And he cut out. Can you tell me what has happened to my friend??*

Big hint:

> Pay attention to the details regarding the forest, snail, bird “running away” and upside down night sky… what could these be hinting at? What did he see on the ground?

Another big hint

> The flag tag can be added too. Also think about where could my friend be, is he in Thailand?

Comment: Next time please don't just post a puzzle without registering on the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vZ69WpKVD4bEGvyCQH7WE6oo5qSPdK3CxfMbNzYcEV4/edit#gid=0) beforehand, we had another puzzle planned for today. Will you award the bounty yourself or should I do it? (it's optional)

Comment: Hey nice to see you again . My bad I am very sorry I will actually allow the person to post his puzzle I did not realize there was a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably way off here but I'm going to take a guess that your friend's..

> plane has crashed on his way to Thailand from Australia and is on **CHRISTMAS ISLAND**

BURNING NOISE =

> THE SOUND OF THE BURNING PLANE WRECK

HE HAS FOUND AND IS DESCRIBING:

> CHRISTMAS ISLAND'S FLAG

PICTURE =

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMTq4.png

FOREST =

> HALF THE FLAG IS GREEN

UPSIDE DOWN SKY =

> THE STARS ARE ON THE BOTTOM OF FLAG

CO =

> CONSTELLATION OF STARS

THE BIRD =

> GOLDEN BOSUN BIRD ON THE FLAG

THE SNAIL =

> THE ISLAND IN THE CENTRE OF FLAG IS SUPPOSED TO BE A SNAIL?

WHY IS HE HERE? =

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6tjR.png - CHRISTMAS ISLAND IS EQUIDISTANT BETWEEN THAILAND AND AUSTRALIA